# iOS Swift : Keep UILabel constantly centered in UIView that changes height

Tags: swift, uiview, height, center

I have a UILabel centered within a UIView that expands/contracts depending on the device screen size. I've applied constraints so that the UILabel remains centered no matter the UIView size, which works fine.

Now I'm finding myself resizing the UIView manually like so (where mainView is the View Controller):

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.mainView.frame.width, self.mainView.frame.height)
```

So this stretches the UIView to fill the whole screen/View Controller (it's also animated). I assumed the UILabel would continue to centre itself automatically, but it seems to pin itself as though it were constrained to the top of the UIView, leaving a lot of empty myView space below it.

How can I tell the UILabel to remain in the centre of the height-changing UIView that it's in?

Comment: We need to see your constraints

Comment: Constraints are just "align center x" and "align center y".

Answer (score 1):

We need to see your constraints to help, but:

1. You need to use centering constraints.
2. Set the bounds, not the frame of myView.
3. You might need to call `setNeedsLayout` on the view of the ViewController you are in

Also, set the background color of the UILabel -- it could be centered, but the text is not centered inside of it.  For that, set the alignment properties.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
1. Definitely using entering constraints.
2. Using bounds makes it even more unpredictable - the UILabel jumps out of myView completely.
3. I think this might be the solution. Haven't used it before, so getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'setNeedsLayout'. Not sure how to fix.
4. I've set this colour, and it looks normal and centered.

Comment: updated... setNeedsLayout is a message of UIView.  Call it on the root view of the view controller.